# Java: Parse string to find the content of brackets

Tags: java, parsing, split, hashtable, brackets

Hi i'm a bit of a beginner, i've been trying to get my head around this for awhile, and i'm wondering can anyone give me a hand.

I have a String, for example

```
The quick <brown> fox jumps over the <lazy> dog
```

What i need to do, is search the string for the contents of each of the < > brackets, and place them into a hashtable, but i can't figure out a clean way to get each word.

Any help would be fantastic, thanks

Comment: Did you try regular expressions? And what non-clean ways did you try?

Comment: I tried repeatedly getting the index of < and > but that became messy pretty quickly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
String yourString = "The quick <brown> fox jumps over the <lazy> dog";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourString);
while(matcher.find()){
   String word = matcher.group(1);
   // do something with the word (like putting it in your hashtable)
}
```